# CSS Keyframe animation: Hiding element before animation starts

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Is there a CSS way to hide an element and fading it in with a keyframe-animation after x seconds? Or do I need JavaScript/jQuery for that? How to do it?

At the moment, it is also show before the animation starts and if I set `opacity: 0;`, the animation jumps back to that value after the animation is complete.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKe2t/)

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/VV2ek/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are close. An easy way is to just add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` which will persist the last keyframe and in this case keep the div visible.

Here's an updated version of your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKe2t/2/) where the animation starts after 4s (as you specified) and keeps the div visible instead of jumping back to it's original state (`opacity: 0;`).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 27):

Easiest method would just be adding this to the CSS:

```
 animation-fill-mode: both;
```

Will hold the animation before and after.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is the only way to hide the div also before the animation starts.

Comment: This was the best answer to me. The accepted one did not work in my case.

Comment: this was the correct answer; i preffer both over forwards

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `@keyframes`, apply the delay with the use of keyframes.

You can change a delay of 4s and an animation duration of 1s into an animation of 5s with keyframes starting at 80%.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88G8P/).

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes slidein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 150px;
    right: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: slidein 5s ease 1 normal;
       -moz-animation: slidein 5s ease 1 normal;
         -o-animation: slidein 5s ease 1 normal;
            animation: slidein 5s ease 1 normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your animation to be something different than a fade-in using opacity, e.g. animate the width; you could put the `opacity:1;` on 1% of the animation:

```
@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    width:0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    width:100px;
  }
}
```

Note that you have to repeat the `opacity:1;` at the end of the animation, i.e. 100%. Otherwise it will fade that element out.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking at using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions) - this page probably has the answer you are looking for.