# Why does my div only animate when i add an attribute of isopen=true but not when i change the value to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on a button I want my div to animate. It seems only the show animation is working, but not the hide. The hide animation doesn't work at all even though the attribute values change.

```js
$("#divShow").click(function() {
  $('.parent').attr('isopen', 'true');
});

$("#divHide").click(function() {
  $('.parent').attr('isopen', 'false');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: none; //hidden by default
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes show {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.90);
  }
}

[isopen="true"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: show .3s;
  -moz-animation: show .3s;
  -ms-animation: show .3s;
  animation: show .3s;
}

[isopen="false"] {
  -webkit-animation: hide .3s;
  -moz-animation: hide .3s;
  -ms-animation: hide .3s;
  animation: hide .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="divShow">Show</button>
<button id="divHide">Hide</button>
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: Because you remove the `display:block` instantly so reverts back to hidden.

Comment: Is there any way so that i can animate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Keyframe animation: Hiding element before animation starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404520/css-keyframe-animation-hiding-element-before-animation-starts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15407098/2181514

you can add `forwards` to your animations so that they keep the last (100%) keyframe.

Add `display:block` to `[isopen=false]` to ensure it doesn't hide immediately then:

```
animation: hide .3s forwards;
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("#divShow").click(function() {
  $('.parent').attr('isopen', 'true');
});

$("#divHide").click(function() {
  $('.parent').attr('isopen', 'false');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: none; 
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes show {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.90);
  }
}

[isopen="true"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: show .3s;
  -moz-animation: show .3s;
  -ms-animation: show .3s;
  animation: show .3s;
}

[isopen="false"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: hide .3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: hide .3s forwards;
  -ms-animation: hide .3s forwards;
  animation: hide .3s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="divShow">Show</button>
<button id="divHide">Hide</button>
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it working as you wanted. See here code snippet below.

Your show class has display block but when you remove it it gets right back to none. Just add the display none at the end of your hide animation.

Like this:

```
@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.90);
    display: none;
  }
}

[isopen="false"] {
  display: block;
  animation: hide .3s forwards;
}
```

Code snippet:

```js
$("#divShow").click(function() {
  $('.parent').attr('isopen', 'true');
});

$("#divHide").click(function() {
  $('.parent').attr('isopen', 'false');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: none; //hidden by default
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

@keyframes show {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.03);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.90);
    display: none;
  }
}

[isopen="true"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: show .3s;
  -moz-animation: show .3s;
  -ms-animation: show .3s;
  animation: show .3s;
}

[isopen="false"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: hide .3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: hide .3s forwards;
  -ms-animation: hide .3s forwards;
  animation: hide .3s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="divShow">Show</button>
<button id="divHide">Hide</button>
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done simply, efficiently with less line of code using transition

```js
$("#divShow").click(function() {
  $('.parent').addClass('show');
});

$("#divHide").click(function() {
  $('.parent').removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
.parent {
   width: 40px;
  height: 40px;background: blue;
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity:0;
  
}

.show {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="divShow">Show</button>
<button id="divHide">Hide</button>
<div class="parent">
</div>
```